# isInitialized property for lateinit isn't working in companion object

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton

I have a singleton class which i have implemented it in java fashion :

```
companion object {

    @Volatile private lateinit var instance: TrapBridge

    fun bridge(): TrapBridge {
        if (!this::instance.isInitialized) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (!this::instance.isInitialized) {
                    instance = TrapBridge()
                }
            }
        }
        return instance
    }

}
```

now the problem is i can't use `isInitialized` property because it throws `NoSuchFieldError` exception :

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field instance of type Lcom/sample/trap/model/TrapBridge; in class Lcom/sample/trap/model/TrapBridge$Companion; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.sample.trap.model.TrapBridge$Companion' appears in /data/app/com.sample.trapsample-L9D8b2vxEQfiSg9Qep_eNw==/base.apk)
```

and i think it's because `instance` is class variable and not instance variable so i can't reference it with `this` keyword :/

also i can't check if it's null because it throws `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` :

```
lateinit property instance has not been initialized
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known issue, tracked [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21862) on the official Kotlin issue tracker.

Comment: Am I right that current workaround is to use a separate `Boolean` variable or nullable data type?

Comment: Yes @Maxim you can use a nullable type & upvote the issue on Jetbrains tracker. This only seems to impact companion objects.

Comment: Got the same issue with a non companion object in kotlin multiplatform int he common part...
`private lateinit var myList: List<Data>` where `::myList.isInitialized` is ignored but `::myList.isAbstract` works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found another way to do this:

```
@Volatile
private lateinit var box: BoxStore
class BoxKeeper private constructor() {
    companion object {
        var instance: BoxStore
            get() = box
            set(_) {}

        fun init(context: Context) {
            if (::box.isInitialized.not())
                box = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(context).build()
        }

    }
}
```