# Access lateinit variable in Companion class

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

I have the following code:

```
abstract class Database : RoomDatabase() {

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        lateinit var INSTANCE: Database
            private set

        fun init(context: Context) {
            val initialized = ::INSTANCE.isInitialized
            if (!initialized) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(...
```

which compiles just fine for some reason. At run-time, when the application started on device this exception is thrown:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type
>   Lpersistance/Database; in class Lpersistance/Database$Companion; or
>   its superclasses (declaration of 'persistance.Database$Companion'
>   appears in /data/app/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk) at
>   persistance.Database$Companion.init(Database.kt:22)

Checking decompiled version of the class, I found that `INSTANCE` variable defined in Database class:

```
public abstract class Database extends RoomDatabase {
   private static volatile Database INSTANCE;
```

`.IsInitialised` code actually represented in Java version that way:

```
public static final class Companion {
   public final Database getINSTANCE() {
      return Database.access$getINSTANCE$cp();
   }
   private final void setINSTANCE(Database var1) {
      Database.INSTANCE = var1;
   }

   public final void init(Context context) {
      boolean initialized = INSTANCE != null;  // error here
      if (!initialized) { ...
```

It's clear that the issue is that the `INSTANCE` variable must be referenced as `Database.INSTANCE`.

Cannot understand, why the code compiles but throws run-time exception and how can I check if `lateinit` variable is initialized?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51007975/4465208

Comment: right. it's definitely duplicate. thx!

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing the same issue.