# Why Kotlin when syntax couldn't fetch value?

Tags: android, kotlin

**I just want to ask why my var `uploadImgsPath` in the Logcat always say: "lateinit property `uploadImgsPath` has not been initialized" ?**

Why `uploadImgsPath` can't fetch value from when syntax?

```
companion object {

        lateinit var categoryDesignID:String
        lateinit var uploadImgsPath:StorageReference
    }

    //Set Spinner
            categoryViewModel.getMainCategoryDesign().observe(this, Observer {
                if (it[0].designTitle != "UnCategorized") {
                    it.add(0, CategoryDesign("", "", "UnCategorized"))
                }
                spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter<CategoryDesign>(
                    context!!,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    it)
                    .apply {
                        setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line)
                    }
                spinner.setSelection(0, false)
                spinner.onItemSelectedListener= object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                    }

                    override fun onItemSelected(
                        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                        view: View?,
                        position: Int,
                        id: Long
                    ) {
                        when (it.get(position).categoryDesignID) {
                            //Setup firebase storage path
                            "" -> {
                                categoryDesignID = ""
                                Toast.makeText(context,"Please choose a category",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}
                            "ClothingDesign" -> {uploadImgsPath = mStorageRef
                                .child("uploadedDesignImgs")
                                .child("ClothingDesign")
                            categoryDesignID = "ClothingDesign" }

                            "CommercialDesign" -> {uploadImgsPath = mStorageRef
                                .child("uploadedDesignImgs")
                                .child("CommercialDesign")
                            categoryDesignID = "CommercialDesign"}

                            "LightingDesign" -> {uploadImgsPath = mStorageRef
                                .child("uploadedDesignImgs")
                                .child("LightingDesign")
                            categoryDesignID = "LightingDesign"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing code that actually accesses `uploadImgsPath`, so for all we know, you're simply accessing it before the `when` executes and assigns a value.

However, not all of your code paths in the `when` assign a value to `uploadImgsPath`:

```
"" -> {
    categoryDesignID = ""
    Toast.makeText(context,"Please choose a category",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

So that could also be a problem.

Comment: There is already a [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51007975/10182897) similar like that

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.
I found reason later and have solved this problem already.
Above codes are totally right.
The issue is because I set firestore's document id to my model's field id,
so when syntex can't match two different id let var uploadImgsPath couldn't fetch any value.